# Estimating derivative for an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Suppose that $f(z)$ is an entire function such that $f(z)/z^n$ is bounded for $|z|\geq R$. SHow that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

As $f(z)$ is an entire function i thought of considering power series expansion $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$

But then this question is asked before introducing power series.

I checked if i can do by using this.

My aim is to prove that $f^{(d)}(0)=0$ for all $d\geq n+1$.

Estimate $$f^{(d)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{d+1}}dz$$

Then i thought i can use that $f(z)/z^n$ is bounded. But then we have that for $z:|z|>R$

Help me in estimating

Comment: In your integral, use $\frac{f(z)}{z^{d+2}}$ instead and estimate the integrand as $\frac{C}{R^2}$.  Now, what happens as $R$ goes to infinity?

Comment: That is my doubt.. It can not be $\frac{C}{R^2}$ as $z<R$ here and not $z>R$... Bound is only when $z>R$ @MichaelBurr

Comment: Use any radius larger than $R$ in the integral and estimate.

Comment: I do not get your point.. Consider explaining a bit more @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $R'>R$ and consider
$$
\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0,R')}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}}dz.
$$
Since you are integrating on the circle of radius $R'$ and $R'>R$ *this is not an integral over a disk*, you know that $\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}}\right|\leq\frac{C}{(R')^2}$ for some constant $C$.

Taking the magnitude of the integral, 
$$
\left|\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0,R')}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}}\,dz\right|\leq\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi}\int_{C(0,R')}\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}}\right|\,|dz|\leq\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi}\int_{C(0,R')}\frac{C}{(R')^2}\,|dz|.
$$

Since the length of a circle of radius $R'$ is $2\pi R'$, you have that 
$$
\left|\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0,R')}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}}dz\right|\leq\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi}\int_{C(0,R')}\frac{C}{(R')^2}\,|dz|\leq\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{2\pi C\cdot R'}{(R')^2}.
$$

Since $R'$ is arbitrary (but larger than $R$), this inequality holds for all $R'$ large enough.  By letting $R'$ go to infinity, you can conclude that $f^{(n+1)}(0)=0$.

Now, generalize for other points and think about what it means that the $(n+1)$st derivative is identically $0$.

Comment: Suppose $n+1$ derivative is zero then $f^{n}=a_n$ some constant then consider its integral $f^{n-1}=a_nz+c$.. Continuing this way we get a polynomial.. So, $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You're welcome Michael.  My pleasure.  -Mark